# c++ - error unzip file (no zip archive)

Tags: java, c++, zip, base64

I have a REST API that have a client (java) and server (c++) and the communication between them is with JSON.

In java I receive a base64 string. This string is a encoded zip archive. I pick this string, do the base64 decoded and create a folder with the zip archive.

**Java code:**

```
Path rootDirectory = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/home/myName/driversFolder");
Path tempDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory(rootDirectory, "");
String dirPath = tempDirectory.toString();
String zipfile = "rbdkjsd4934234234adadds==" //base64 string test
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dirPath + "/zipf.zip");
fos.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode(tt));
fos.close();
```

If I go to the folder `/home/myName/driversFolder/8434224994994` (`8434224994994` is a temporary folder) I can see a zip (`zipf.zip`) archive and inside the zip I have the content. So the `base64` decoder is working fine.

Now in my server I need to go to the previous folder and unzip the file. I'm using the [libzip](https://nih.at/libzip/).

This is the code I have to open the zip archive:

```
struct zip *z;
struct zip_file *zf;
struct zip_stat sb;
int err = 0;
int len;
int fd;
char buf[100];

std::string zipfile = "/home/myName/driversFolder/8434224994994/zipf.zip";

if ( (z = zip_open(zipfile.c_str(), 0, &err)) == NULL )
{
  zip_error_to_str(buf, sizeof(buf), err, errno);
  fprintf(stderr, "can't open zip archive `%s': %s/n", zipfile.c_str(), buf);
  return 1;
}
```

And I'm getting the follow error:

```
"can't open zip archive '/home/myName/driversFolder/8434224994994/zipf.zip' 
Not a zip archive"
```

If I create a folder (I test with a single folder and a single file inside them) and compress to zip and try to do the unzip file it works. But for the previous zip archive from the `base64` it's not working. But my `zipf.zip` is a zip archive. I'm using a linux, I go to archive proprieties and the type is : "`Zip archive (application/zip)`".

Why is it in this case the libzip said that the file is not a zip archive? It is a zip archive!

Comment: Can you unzip it w/another program that you didn't write?

Comment: I test now to use the c++ code directly with the original zip, and it works. So probably the problem is in java with the way i decoded the string and create the zip. Its strange because the decoded create a zip archive (in zip format) and inside i have the all files. But in c++ we dont recognize this with a zip file. The base64 decoded with some way create a zipfile yes but the libzip in c++ dont recognize.... why?

Comment: In linux if i try do decompress the zipfile before doing the base64 decode its works good and decompress to a zip with all content

Comment: My question is, why use zip? Gunzip is a better solution, especially if the system you are sending it to is a linux based system.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. But why the java client decoded the base64 string and create a zip file but in this case the libzip dont recognize as a zip? Its only on this case. Like i said, is pick the original zip archive (without base64 encoded) and try do decompress with libzip he recognize as a zip and its works..